# (Manjaro Linux) OpenMPI not running any kind of compiled C multiprocess program

Tags: c, eclipse, mpi, openmpi, manjaro

I have Manjaro Linux 17.1.10 (kernel 4.17.0-2) in a ThinkPad T420 (Core i5 2450M, Upgraded to 8GB RAM) and I'm trying to run some C programs using OpenMPI (version 3.1.0) but I'm having troubles running the programs.

I am able to compile them without issues both from terminal using `mpicc` and Ecplipse's "build" option, but when I try to run them, either from terminal or in Eclipse (configured as a parallel aplication in launch options) I face errors, no matter the code that I run.

I'm trying to run the MPI hello world C project that comes with Ecipse Parallel:

```
/*
 ============================================================================
 Name        : test.c
 Author      : MGMX
 Version     : 1
 Copyright   : GNU 3.0
 Description : Hello MPI World in C 
 ============================================================================
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int  my_rank; /* rank of process */
    int  p;       /* number of processes */
    int source;   /* rank of sender */
    int dest;     /* rank of receiver */
    int tag=0;    /* tag for messages */
    char message[100];        /* storage for message */
    MPI_Status status ;   /* return status for receive */

    /* start up MPI */

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    /* find out process rank */
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank); 

    /* find out number of processes */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p); 


    if (my_rank !=0){
        /* create message */
        sprintf(message, "Hello MPI World from process %d!", my_rank);
        dest = 0;
        /* use strlen+1 so that '\0' get transmitted */
        MPI_Send(message, strlen(message)+1, MPI_CHAR,
           dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else{
        printf("Hello MPI World From process 0: Num processes: %d\n",p);
        for (source = 1; source < p; source++) {
            MPI_Recv(message, 100, MPI_CHAR, source, tag,
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("%s\n",message);
        }
    }
    /* shut down MPI */
    MPI_Finalize(); 


    return 0;
}
```

If I run the program using simple `./test` without parameters I have an output:

```
[mgmx@ThinkPad Debug]$ ./test
Hello MPI World From process 0: Num processes: 1
```

but if I use `mpirun` i have different results, depending of the number pof procecess (`-np #`) i select; but all of them throw error:

```
[mgmx@ThinkPad Debug]$ mpirun -np 0 test
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
[mgmx@ThinkPad Debug]$ mpirun -np 1 test
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[49948,1],0]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mgmx@ThinkPad Debug]$ mpirun -np 2 test
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
[mgmx@ThinkPad Debug]$ mpirun -np 3 test
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 3 slots
that were requested by the application:
  test

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots available
for use.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mgmx@ThinkPad Debug]$ mpirun -np 4 test
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 4 slots
that were requested by the application:
  test

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots available
for use.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am running everything local.

Here is the ouput of `--version` both in mpicc and mpirun:

```
[mgmx@ThinkPad Debug]$ mpicc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.1.1 20180531
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Esto es software libre; vea el código para las condiciones de copia.  NO hay
garantía; ni siquiera para MERCANTIBILIDAD o IDONEIDAD PARA UN PROPÓSITO EN
PARTICULAR

[mgmx@ThinkPad Debug]$ mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 3.1.0

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
```

[And Eclipse's "about" window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53GLe.png)

Also I installed OpenMPI in various ways: from the Manjaro Repository using pacman, using pamac (a pacman/yaourt GUI) and the git version from the AUR using both yaourt and pamac.